# Background image with cutouts

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button, android-drawable

I am setting a layout's background with an image with two cutouts. Inside cutouts, I want to have a button and a textview element as shown in diagram below.

```
imgimgimgimgimgimgimg
imgimgimgimgimgimgimg
img            imgimg
img   button   imgimg
img            imgimg
imgimgimgimgimgimgimg
img            imgimg
img   TextView imgimg
img            imgimg
imgimgimgimgimgimgimg
imgimgimgimgimgimgimg
```

In different layouts (devices), the placement of button and Textview get shifted. So, I created
different scaled images for each drawable-folder. However, the elements (button and textview) are still shifted for example between  3.7"WVGA and 3.7"FWVGA. Maybe I am doing it wrong.

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: You could use a 9 patch image here if possible.

Comment: The img is that of a car. Looks like using 9 patch will distort it to an unacceptable level.

Comment: Could you show a sample/screenshot?

Comment: Ok here are the images: http://imgur.com/Hrh7nPL,43O7IJd#0 and http://imgur.com/Hrh7nPL,43O7IJd#1 as examples